# Application State using locationManager

Tags: ios, swift2, core-location, cllocationmanager

Sorry if this question is too basic, but I'm stuck.

Scenario:

My app uses background and suspended locationUpdates using startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges.
in my AppDelegate I have:

```
    if let options = launchOptions {
        locationKey = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey] as! Bool
    }
```

So when app is launched by location manager, my locationKey = true.

I was hoping to use locationKey inside the app to distinguish location manager launching or user launching.

The problem is:

When the app is launched by location manager, the behavior is exactly as when user launch the app, I mean, all views (from launch process) are instantiated, but app still "closed".

When I tap to open the app, it is "like" is already opened, so, I can't verify my locationKey, because it is always true and AppDelegate (didFinishLaunchingWithOptions) is not triggered again and then is quite hard to figure out how I can process the startup in its different ways, user and location.

My question is, how can I identify that the app was launched by location and when user really open the app I "restore" its normal way ?

Thank you and sorry if it's not clear

Answer (score 0):

can you be a bit more clear about the behaviour you expect for your app?

The app won't ever be launched by location :

once the user launch the app (triggering didFinishLaunchingWithOptions), 
the app can go into background mode (aka being suspended) and can do some work (like updating locations, finishing some tasks, or delegating unfinished downloads to the system so then can finish) or is killed.

When the user come back to the app either the app was in background and switch to foreground mode or it was killed and didFinishLaunchingWithOptions will be invoke again to relaunch the app completly.

Comment: The app is launched by locationmanager, not by the user in this case. It runs when is killed, but internal behavior and instances get same behavior as user has launched, that is my "problem"